# Access a calculated column using a sub-query with a conditional

Tags: sql, subquery, hiveql

I'm working with some payments balances for different clients and I want to use a calculated column in a sub-query. Breakdown of what I'm working with:

Step 1: I'm basically pulling clients id's, names, deposit balances and payment outflows.
Step 2: Sum(deposit balance)/count(distinct business accounts) - average deposits
Step 3: Sum(payment outflows)/count(distinct business accounts) - average outflows
**Step 4: ??? Use the average outflows calculated in the previous column with a set of conditions to assign a multiplication factor ??? i.e.:

when avg outflow > x then multiplication_factor=2

when avg outflow > y then multiplication_factor=5

etc.**

Would appreciate any suggestions on how to tackle step 4 and proceed.

I haven't used SQL in a while and here is what I've come up with so far:

```
Select parent_id, parent_name, deposits, payments  
, sum(deposits)/count(distinct business_accts) avg_deposits  
, sum(payments)/count(distinct business_accts) avg_payments  
, ??? multiplication_factor (  
      case  
      when avg_payments > x then multiplication_factor=1   
      when avg_payments > y then multiplication_factor=2  
      etc.  
      end  
)  
FROM Table_pyb  
WHERE something something;
```

I doubt if I can access the avg_payments columns in a sub-query... suggestions would be much appreciated :)

Comment: repeat the average calculation, or when you need it for calcluation make a cte with the average and then caculate it

Comment: when I repeat the avg calculation it applies the multiplication_factor to each row individually and not at the aggregate level (which is what I intend). You mentioned cte... can you please expand on how I should use it.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42485849/how-cte-common-table-expression-in-hive-gets-evaluated  here a cTe first calculates the vlaues you ned and in the SELECT after you can use the columns you created